# MariaDB 10.1.21 Galera Cluster fails to start with error "Can´t create test file" / datadir confusion

Tags: mysql, service, mariadb, startup

We are running a galera cluster with 3 nodes. 
Today we had to shutdown one of the nodes.
The configuration did not change. 
We have a different location for the datadir (/mysql/data).

During start we get the following log entries:

1. sh[11760]: [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.21-MariaDB) starting as process 11966 ...
2. sh[11760]: WSREP: Recovered position ded77f9d-d376-11e5-a55e-aafa472da560:34239402
3. mysqld[11999]: [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.21-MariaDB) starting as process 11999 ...
4. mysqld[11999]: [Warning] Can't create test file **/var/lib/mysql**/node3.lower-test
5. mysqld[11999]: [97B blob data]
6. mysqld[11999]: [ERROR] Aborting

"mysqld --print-defaults" shows "--datadir=/mysql/data"

When I create the directory "/var/lib/mysql" it does not only try to create a test-file, but all system-tables.

SELinux is disabled.

It looks like mariadb ignores my configuration. What am I doing wrong?